# Does anyone know of a good tutorial for making GUIs in MATLAB w/ GUIDE?

Tags: matlab

I want to creat a GUI using the GUIDE tool in MATLAB.  Anyone know of a good tutorial (preferably not a video...can't watch).

THanks

Comment: Duplicate: [How to program MATLAB's GUI](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115703/how-to-program-matlabs-gui). The [answer from ThibThib](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115703/how-to-program-matlabs-gui/1115721#1115721) in particular links to two good non-video tutorials.

Comment: For non-GUIDE programmatic examples, check out the "41 Complete GUI Examples" submission on FEX by Matt Fig: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24861-41-complete-gui-examples

Comment: GUIDE is really easy, I mean extremely easy. IMO you can just start with GUIDE MATLAB Help and and after few clicks you will master it. With MATLAB it is not possible to create beautiful resizable GUI's anyway but MATLAB UI is thousand times less complex then Java Swing or .NET WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apart from what can normally be found at Google "MATLAB GUI GUIDE" no. Most of them are useful, but many lack a systematic approach.

However, I remember a rather nice book - had it in my possesion back then (when I didn't need it), don't have it now when I do need it. It was called [*Graphics and GUIs with MATLAB*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584883200). It really nicely explained some general idioms when building a GUI. Also *[Mastering MATLAB 7](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131430181)*.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nice [site](http://blinkdagger.com/matlab/matlab-gui-graphical-user-interface-tutorial-for-beginners/) with great screenshots.  No video as requested.