# image restoration gui

Tags: matlab

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I program a GUI in MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115703/how-can-i-program-a-gui-in-matlab)

i'm developing an image restoration mini-project using matlab.is there simple tool to build gui ?

Comment: Great comment, mdm. I voted to close the question as duplicate.

Comment: @mdm: *Let me Google that For You* links [are banned here,](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15650/ban-lmgtfy-let-me-google-that-for-you-links) and obfuscating the link with an URL shortener suggests that **you already knew that.**

Answer (score 1):

The built-in Matlab tool GUIDE will guide you through that process.