# Warning Message when someone is closing GUI in Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, warnings, message

How can I make warning message in GUI Matlab, when the user is closing the gui (using rght top 'x').

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I program a GUI in MATLAB?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115703/how-can-i-program-a-gui-in-matlab)

Comment: This is most definitely NOT a duplicate of referenced post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [set the figure's `CloseRequestFcn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/the-figure-close-request-function.html) to, for example, ask the user if they really want to close the figure or not. You can use a built-in modal window, like [`questdlg`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/questdlg.html), for this purpose. An [example of such a function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/the-figure-close-request-function.html#bscueci) is given in the above documentation:

```
function my_closereq(src,evnt)
% User-defined close request function
% to display a question dialog box
   selection = questdlg('Close This Figure?',...
                        'Close Request Function',...
                        'Yes','No','Yes');
   switch selection,
      case 'Yes',
         delete(gcf)
      case 'No'
         return 
   end
end
```